# run a program under a limited user account

Tags: delphi

i want to develop a program that will process images and show all esxisting images with details like "picasa photo viewer",also i have a windows service that gathering new images,it will run under "Local System Account",but in limited user account my program don't work,how i can run my program from limited user account ? thx for ur time

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.  What doesn't it do? What sort of things go wrong when it tries to do it? Does it give any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the program breaks in limited account, it is asking for something it cannot get.
I'd start with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - it shows you what files/registry entries/etc your program is accessing, and whether it's successful or fails. Many times, the issue is something quite trivial - e.g. trying to write to the HKLM registry hive and failing to recover from "Permission denied".

Also, check out [Aaron Margosis' page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627005437/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/11/03/luabuglight.aspx), the "LUA Buglight" program can help you find more issues that can crop up in limited mode.